# Differentiation of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to solve the following problem:
"Consider thee branch of $f(z) = \sqrt{z(1-z)}$ on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$ that has positive imaginary part at $z = 2$. What is $f'(z)$? Be sure to specify the branch of the expression for $f'(z)$."

My idea for solving the problem was to take the derivative of $f(z)$, just as if it was a normal derivative and substitute $z =2$ to consider the branch expression for $f'(z)$. However, my professor solved it by taking the derivative of the expression $f(z)^2 = z(1-z)$ and solving for $f'(z)$.

I don't really understand why I should do it as my professor and not just differentiating the expression as it is given. Could someone explain this? Also, when it says to specify the branch of $f'(z)$ what should we do in this part? Thanks!